# unexpected token error calling a function in a callback

Tags: javascript, callback, syntax-error, anonymous-function

on the call back after the ajax call in qm150_submit $.post ....
I want to call a second function called 'send_email'  (which also has a callback called 'success_callback'

I am getting an error here

```
function () {send_email(fromName,fromEmail,toEmail,subject,message,success_callback) };
```

error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

here is the code :

```
function qm150_submit($title, $name, $email, $description, $send_email) {

  $.post('<?PHP print API_SUBMIT; ?>', { "title": $title, "name": $name, "email": $email, "description": $description },
    function (data) {          // callback function after API_SUBMIT

    // Send email with a link to their collection
      if ($send_email) {

        // parameters for the send_email() ajax function

        var subject = "subject";
        var collection_id = data.collection_id;  // data is json returned from the ajax above
        var toEmail = $email
        var message = "<?PHP print SHARE_COLLECTION;?>"+collection_id;
        var fromEmail = "<?PHP print EMAIL_FROM_EMAIL; ?>";
        var fromName = "<?PHP print EMAIL_FROM_NAME; ?>";

        var success_callback = function (results) { 
          alert('send_email has returned with: '+results);
        };

        alert('I am now calling the send_email');
        function () {send_email(fromName,fromEmail,toEmail,subject,message,success_callback) };

      }
    });
        // missing a curly bracket ? no! note  double indentation of the anonymous function (data) is a continuation of first statement
}
```

edit: and the code for the send_email()

```
function send_email(fromName,fromEmail,toEmail,subject,message,success_callback) {
  alert('send_email called');
  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '<?PHP print API_SHARE_EMAIL;?>',
    data: 'fromName=' + fromName + '&fromEmail=' + fromEmail + '&toEmail=' + toEmail + '&subject=' + subject + '&message=' + message,
    dataType:'json',
    success: success_callback
  });
  alert('send_email finished');
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unexpected token is the `(` after `function`.

First of all, you're declaring an anonymous function without ever calling it. Secondly, an anonymous function declaration cannot be a statement (or in other words, a function statement must have a name), which is why the `(` is unexpected (javascript expects a function name, not parantheses).

Simply call `send_email` directly... It's already inside a function, so it won't "pollute" the global object (there's nothing to pollute it with anyway) - I see no need for an anonymous function:

```
alert('I am now calling the send_email for real!');
send_email(fromName, fromEmail, toEmail, subject, message, success_callback);
```

Comment: that makes sense, now I have a reference problem, getting this error when from that secondcallback `Uncaught TypeError: Property 'send_email' of object [object DOMWindow] is not a function`  I will start a new question if unless you or someone has some quick advice

Comment: Well, it seems your function is actually called `$send_email`, not `send_email`? Wouldn't know for sure without seeing more of your code.

Comment: $send_email is a variable that is either true or false, send_email() is a function that is supposed to be called if $send_email is true. I will edit my post to include the send_email() function.

Comment: The error you get indicates that there's something declared globally (on `window` which is what the browser means by `DOMWindow`) called `send_email`, which *isn't* a function. You may be overwriting the function elsewhere in the script - for example by assigning to a variable you haven't declared (`send_email = true;` rather than `var send_email = true;`)

Comment: I have started a new question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9247706/uncaught-typeerror-property-of-object-object-domwindow-is-not-a-function). I will flag this as the answer to this question and consider your advice here in regards to my new question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you check your code with JSLint you will get this error:

> Function statements cannot be placed in blocks. Use a function expression or move the statement to the top of the outer function.

You have to wrap the anonymous function like this: `(function{})();`

Fixed code:

```
function qm150_submit($title, $name, $email, $description, $send_email) {

$.post('<?PHP print API_SUBMIT; ?>', {
    "title": $title,
    "name": $name,
    "email": $email,
    "description": $description
}, function(data) { // callback function after API_SUBMIT
    // Send email with a link to their collection
    if ($send_email) {

        // parameters for the send_email() ajax function
        var subject = "subject";
        var collection_id = data.collection_id; // data is json returned from the ajax above
        var toEmail = $email;
        var message = "<?PHP print SHARE_COLLECTION;?>" + collection_id;
        var fromEmail = "<?PHP print EMAIL_FROM_EMAIL; ?>";
        var fromName = "<?PHP print EMAIL_FROM_NAME; ?>";

        var success_callback = function(results) {
            alert('send_email has returned with: ' + results);
        };

        alert('I am now calling the send_email');

        (function() {
            send_email(fromName, fromEmail, toEmail, subject, message, success_callback);
        })();

    }
});
}​
```

Or simply remove that anonymous function that does nothing:

```
send_email(fromName, fromEmail, toEmail, subject, message, success_callback);

instead of:

(function() {send_email(fromName, fromEmail, toEmail, subject, message, success_callback);
        })();
```

Comment: with that change the function is being called on load of any page that has the script, whereas I want it only to be called as a callback to to the $.post() function