# Uncaught TypeError: Property of object [object DOMWindow] is not a function

Tags: javascript, callback, typeerror

on the call back after the ajax call in qm150_submit $.post ....
I want to call a second function called 'send_email'  (which also has a callback called 'success_callback'

the send_email is called but I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'send_email' of object [object DOMWindow] is not a function
```

is this a reference error? do I need to do something to set what ever `.this` is perhaps??

function `qm150_submit()` is called from with an colorbox iframe. I'm not sure if that has anything to do with it ?

here is the code :

```
function qm150_submit($title, $name, $email, $description, $send_email) {

  $.post('<?PHP print API_SUBMIT; ?>', { "title": $title, "name": $name, "email": $email, "description": $description },
    function (data) {          // callback function after API_SUBMIT

    // Send email with a link to their collection
      if ($send_email) {

        // parameters for the send_email() ajax function

        var subject = "subject";
        var collection_id = data.collection_id;  // data is json returned from the ajax above
        var toEmail = $email
        var message = "<?PHP print SHARE_COLLECTION;?>"+collection_id;
        var fromEmail = "<?PHP print EMAIL_FROM_EMAIL; ?>";
        var fromName = "<?PHP print EMAIL_FROM_NAME; ?>";

        var success_callback = function (results) { 
          alert('send_email has returned with: '+results);
        };

        alert('I am now calling the send_email');
        send_email(fromName,fromEmail,toEmail,subject,message,success_callback);

      }
    });
        // missing a curly bracket ? no! note  double indentation of the anonymous function (data) is a continuation of first statement
}
```

and the code for the send_email()

```
function send_email(fromName,fromEmail,toEmail,subject,message,success_callback) {
  alert('send_email called');
  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '<?PHP print API_SHARE_EMAIL;?>',
    data: 'fromName=' + fromName + '&fromEmail=' + fromEmail + '&toEmail=' + toEmail + '&subject=' + subject + '&message=' + message,
    dataType:'json',
    success: success_callback
  });
  alert('send_email finished');
  return true;
}
```

Comment: You may want to post the rest of the .js-file somewhere, since it's likely that you're overwriting the `send_email` function with something that isn't a function elsewhere in the script. Plus, you haven't included the changes from the previous question (proper `send_email` call), which may mislead people - and, well, turns out it did...

Comment: @TheKaneda your changes have now been included, my mistake. Thanks for your help

Comment: the main window and the colorbox iframe both include the same script.

Comment: I am checking for other references to send_email in the include script. and in the html files invvolved

Comment: Then, again, we need to see the rest (SO would like to be "self contained", but use https://gist.github.com/ or something, then move the relevant bit here, when we figure out what the problem is). Because, safe for a missing `;` after `var toEmail = $email` (which won't cause an error), there's nothing wrong with the code you've posted. Something else is causing the problem.

Comment: You were right @TheKaneda I had overwritten the function in a globally defined variable in a script within the iframe (not included in the code above). Thanks for your troubleshooting advice. If I could vote a comment as an answer you would get it !

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
function () {send_email(fromName,fromEmail,toEmail,subject,message,success_callback) };
```

Just call the function.

```
send_email(fromName,fromEmail,toEmail,subject,message,success_callback);
```

Comment: sorry about that, as recognised by TheKaneda @TheKaneda, I had incorrectly posted the code that had been corrected on a previous question. Please see the edit now applied. Thanks for the help everyone.